# Do any languages use a 'do X if Y' syntax?

Tags: if-statement, syntax, programming-languages

Just out of curiosity, does anyone know of a language that uses a "reverse" if/then statement?

For example,

```
if(a == b) {
    doC();
}
```

in most languages would be

```
{
    doC();
} if(a == b)
```

in this language.

I know it won't work in most languages (like C#, for instance) that execute up to down, left to right, but are there *any* languages that use or support such a syntax?

Comment: Vax Basic used to allow it.  There were a few others, back in the day.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is nothing more "up to down, left to right" about C#. C syntax isn't special compared to Perl, ruby, or python, which all have this feature. This would work just fine with C# syntax. It's syntax which is separate from the execution. The implementers just didn't add it.

Comment: good to know, thanks! probably shouldn't make assumptions about languages based on a quick skim of some docs ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can do this in Perl. This:

```
if (a == b) {
    doC();
}
```

Can be written this way:

```
do {
  doC();
} if (a == b);
```

It’s often used to make preconditions easier to read:

```
while (<>) {
  last if /<END>/;  # Exit loop if current line contains "<END>".
  print;
}
```

And Ruby borrows this feature from Perl.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `A if cond else B` statement in [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/995714)

For example

```python
print('kid') if age < 18 else print('adult')
```

Comment: This is just an ordinary expression statement that happens to use the `… if … else …` conditional operator. This example works in Python 3 where `print` is a function, but not in Python 2.

Comment: @JonPurdy then what's the problem with this? The OP asked about a language that has reversed if condition

Answer (score 1):

Ruby, Python (as Lưu Vĩnh Phúc said) support that kind of style.
This is Ruby's way:

```
puts :hello if true
```

In the Moonscript there are ["line decorators"](http://moonscript.org/reference/#line_decorators) :

```
print "hello world" if name == "Rob"
```

They differ a little from the Ruby's ifs so I put them into another category.

Another group are concatenative or stack based programming languages.  You can read more about it [here](http://concatenative.org/wiki/view/Concatenative%20language).
They do not exactly do what you described but they are close.
In the [Factor](http://factorcode.org/) you can write:

```
10 3 <
[ "yes" ]
[ "no" ]
if
```

I believe that syntax where the condition is just before `if` is possible. After all `10 3 <` is evaluated to the `f` (Factor's false value) so it does not matter where `f` is on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

How about the `do while` loop in php? Of course, the code would always get executed **at least** once within the do loop but it partially does what you might be looking for.

```php
<?php
$i = 0;
do {
    echo $i;
} while ($i > 0);
?>
```

Comment: this is pretty much what I was thinking about, and do/while works in most languages (javascript & c# off the top of my head), but I was more looking for something that (as you pointed out) will only get executed if the statement is true.

do/while still works in C# and makes sense because it's still reading up-down, left-right. I'm looking for a language that doesn't follow that pattern

Comment: Any particular reason why you are looking for a language that digresses from the traditional top/down parsing methodology?